# How to name a jQuery function to make a browser's back button work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function to ajaxyfy a web site, everything works perfect, except function for a back button.

That's what I have for now:

```
function loading() {
    if (typeof history.pushState !== "undefined") {
        var historyCount = 0;

        $('.menu-item, .logo').on('click','a',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).data('clicked', true);
            if ($(this).is('.logo a')) {
            var homepage = $(this).attr('href');
                function1(homepage);
                history.pushState(null, null, homepage);
            }
        else if ($(this).is('.projects a')) {
                var projects = $(this).attr('href');
                function2(projects);
                history.pushState(null, null, projects);    
        }
        else {
                var pages = $(this).attr('href');
                function3(pages);
                history.pushState(null, null, pages);
        }

        });
        window.onpopstate = function(){
            if(historyCount) {
                goTo(document.location);
            }
            historyCount = historyCount+1;
        };
    }
}


function function1(homepage) {
    $.ajax({
        url: homepage,
        success: function(data) {
           $('.container_right_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 300, function(){
                $(this).html(data).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 300);
                console.log('home');
            });
        }
    });
}


function function2(projects) {
    $.ajax({
        url: projects,
        success: function(data) {
           $('.container_right_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 300, function(){
                $(this).html(data).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 300);
                console.log('projects');
            });
        }
    });
}


function function3(pages) {
    $.ajax({
        url: pages,
        success: function(data) {
           $('.container_right_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 300, function(){
                $(this).html(data).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 300);
                console.log('page');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and there is a problem with

```
 window.onpopstate = function(){
        if(historyCount) {
            goTo(document.location);
        }
        historyCount = historyCount+1;
    };
```

If I leave **goTo** it doesn't work at all, if i put a name of any other function, i.e. **function1**, it works only for function 1. How to make it work for all three functions regardless of what function has been triggered?

**EDIT**

What I'm really concrned about is function:

```
 window.onpopstate = function(){
        if(historyCount) {
            goTo(document.location);
        }
        historyCount = historyCount+1;
    };
```

It's name is, as can be clearly seen, *goTo* (because primarily it was related to a function named *goTo(href)*). In *if* conditional tags I call functions: *function1*, *function2*, *function3*, which replaced earlier existent function *goTo(href)*. When I divided function to three idividual functions, above *window.popstate...* function stopped to work. I need to have three different function because I need to three different thing happen when clicking on different menu buttons. I can replace *goTo* with *function1* or *function2* ...etc, but then the back button works only for the oneof those three functions. And I want it to work for all of them.

Comment: If you just want to figure out how to code this correctly, great.  If you'd just like a working back button, check out [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), simplifies things tremendously.

Comment: If you want the function like the browsers back button then you can write <a href="#" onclick='javascript:history.go(-1)'></a>

Comment: @Pramod if his website is "ajaxified", `javascript:history.go(-1)` will screw up everything. He is looking for a function to get the previous content received by ajax.

Comment: Well, it's not like I want to find a function. I already hve a function but I only want to adjust it to an exmple above. See EDIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to do everything by myself. I digged a bit deeper into HTML5 push.state and and I made following changes:

I changed

```
history.pushState(null, null, homepage);
```

to:

```
history.pushState('function1', null, homepage);
```

I did analogous changes to two other *push.state* functions. Then I replaced

```
window.onpopstate = function(){
  if(historyCount) {
    goTo(document.location);
  }
historyCount = historyCount+1;
};
```

with:

```
window.onpopstate = function(){
  if(historyCount) {
  var JSONattr = (JSON.stringify(event.state).replace(/\"/g, ""));
    window[JSONattr](document.location);
  }
historyCount = historyCount+1;
};
```

what pulls a name of every of three functions from *push.state*, and thanks to that, with every browser's back button hit, the desired function is being executed.